# What is the default background colour for NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I'm working on a simple editor with multiple cells to edit dates in AppKit. I draw the control myself and it doesn't inherit from NSTextField. I was trying to use `NSColor.textBackgroundColor` to be its background color. That seems to work ok for the light appearance. But in the dark appearance, I get a black background color. I tried to use also some other `NSColor` colors, but with no luck.

What color should I use for the background color to achieve the same result as in `NSTextField`?

[image: !Illustration of the problem - on the top is my editor, bottom editor s NSTextField]

Comment: I think there's a vibrancy effect, so the exact colour depends on what wallpaper behind your app

Comment: IB says text background color. However, it seems that @Alexander is right. When I move the window around the screen, it shows always slightly different color. Also Apple doc on `NSVisualEffectView` tells:  `NSTextField enables vibrancy to increase the contrast between the text and background.`. So, I will experiment a little with `NSVisualEffectView` (no luck to find the exact way so far).